# How to make a toplevel perform like a panel?

Tags: gtk, panel, x11

I'm writing a small program, which needs to perform like a panel. Now I have a problem. Windows will still take the place of it, if windows are maximized. (in fact, behind it)

My toplevel window has become a window that is "always on top". I used

```
gtk_window_set_type_hint(GTK_WINDOW (self), GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DOCK);
```

But this problem still troubles me.

Any ideas? Thanks.

PS: My program is written in GTK+, runs on X11.

---

Now this problem has been solved with following code,

```
void
hs_x_set_hint_strut (GdkWindow *window,
                     int        left,
                     int        right,
                     int        top,
                     int        bottom)
{
    GdkAtom atom;

    long vals[4];
    vals[0] = left;
    vals[1] = right;
    vals[2] = top;
    vals[3] = bottom;

    atom = gdk_atom_intern ("_NET_WM_STRUT", FALSE);

    gdk_property_change (window, atom, gdk_x11_xatom_to_atom (XA_CARDINAL), 
                         32, GDK_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, (guchar *)vals, 4);
}

void
hs_x_set_window_strut (GtkWindow *window)
{
    GdkWindow *gdk_win;
    GdkRectangle win_rect;

    g_return_if_fail (GTK_IS_WINDOW (window));
    gdk_win = gtk_widget_get_window (GTK_WIDGET (window));
    gdk_window_get_geometry (gdk_win, NULL, NULL, 
                             NULL, &win_rect.height);
    hs_x_set_hint_strut (gdk_win, 0, 0, win_rect.height, 0);
}
```

Thanks for Andrey Sidorov's help!

Comment: Sorry but your problem is not quite clear. Do you mean to say that your window panel which is expected to be on top all time is obscured by other top level windows. It might be important to note that window management is not part of Gtk. Set the hint for a window is a *hint* to the window manager, which the window manager may/may not choose to honor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [_NET_WM_STRUT / _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#NETWMSTRUT) hints

Comment: Should this be set with `XChangeProperty`? Or with `XSendEvent`?

Comment: ChangeProperty. ( this is what requires a message to be sent to a root window: http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#idm140130317705584 )